# Modify "Add Post" link in Wordpress custom post type

Tags: wordpress, action

I'm sure I need an action hook, but I can't find one. I need to add a query to the URL used by the "add contact" link on my custom post type:

http://radleygh.com/images/chrome_2013-073-14-39-44-83.png

In edit.php, there is a variable called `$post_new_file` which is what I need to add to. There is a function that might  help, `$wp_list_table->current_action`, but it does not seem to affect the `$post_new_file` variable. It is assigned to a variable called `$doaction` but I do not think it is related to `add_action` hooks.

Can anyone point me in the right direction? I might get away with output buffering and a preg replace, but that seems a bit overkill. There does not seem to be any action calls between when `$post_new_file` is defined, and when it is written in HTML.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is possible, and not too hard, though it took awhile to work out.

```
function reset_post_new_link() {
  global $post_new_file,$post_type_object;
  if (!isset($post_type_object) || 'post-type-name' != $post_type_object->name) return false;
  $post_new_file = $post_new_file."append-what-want"
}
add_action('admin_head','reset_post_new_link');
```

`$post_type_object` is there so you can limit where this runs. You probably want to limit it by even more criteria but I will leave that up to you.

Also, I am pretty sure this in not officially supported, so be warned.

Comment: This appears to work just fine! I have it set up so that you can filter by category, and wanted to make it so if you are viewing  the category "Advisory Board", clicking "Add Contact" would auto-fill the category 'Advisory Board'. It's very slick. Thank you!

Comment: I was also looking for this function/method. I tried the action hook `in_admin_head` because I thought I could override `$post_new_file` this way. The hook worked, but for some reason it didn't override the variable (maybe someone can explain this? or wherefore the `in_admin_head` could be used instead). I found your answer and changed the action hook into `admin_head` and it works now. Thank you for sharing with us!